# Integrating Google Earth historical imagery within Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-engine, historical-imagery

I'm planning on doing a high res. land cover classification of Southeast Asia for the last 20 years. I'd like to use Google Earth Engine Code Editor for the easy-access to Landsat data/ability to easily create time series/training data/etc., **but** also need to view high resolution historical imagery on occasion, e.g. the kind you can get via Google Earth Pro's historical imagery slider.

Is there some way to integrate the two within Earth Engine? Right now I'm just using coordinates to reference the same location between the two platforms, but  re-tying lat/lon again and again between the two platforms is inefficient and I need to streamline my training data collection process.

I know you can do `Export.map.toCloudStorage()`, but Google Earth web doesn't have the historical functionality....

Any suggestions on how to integrate the two?

Comment: In a word - no. You won't be able to access the commercial high-res data available in Earth from within Earth Engine. It sounds like your goal is to make your training data collection easier. Instead of typing you could export a KML from Earth Engine and then edit the required points within Earth Pro and re-ingest that KML file back into Earth Engine. Would that help?

Comment: Alternatively there are tools that integrate Google Earth and Google Earth Engine. Maybe have a look at [OpenForis Collect Earth](http://www.openforis.org/tools/collect-earth.html).